# A simple autokeyloop which presses E and holds it down for 2 seconds

Tags: autohotkey

I'm just trying to make a simple loop in autohotkey that starts when i press ctrl+y
and presses e and holds it down for 2 seconds

^t::
loop
{
keysend,e
keyWait,T,2
}
return
I'm new to this software so I'd like an explanation of how it works and not just the code please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just press E for 2 seconds and then release:

```
^y::
Send, {e down}
Sleep, 2000
Send, {e up}
return
```

The code is pretty self-explaining, You hold e down, wait 2000 ms, and release it again.

To repeatedly do it until you press the key again:

```
^y::
if (not KeyActive)
    {
    Send, {e down}
    SetTimer, ReleaseAndPressAgain, 2000
}
else
    {
    Send, {e up}
    SetTimer, ReleaseAndPressAgain, Off
}
KeyActive := !KeyActive
return

ReleaseAndPressAgain:
Send, {e up}
Send, {e down}
return
```

This holds e down and creates a Timer named ReleaseAndPressAgain that every 2000 ms releases e and presses it again. Pressing the hotkey again releases e and stops the timer. Whether the hotkey is currently active is stored in the variable KeyActive.

If you are interested any further, I recommend the official documentation at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/.